# Llamar al login e iniciar sesión después de registro en php

Tags: php, login, redirección, registro

Tengo este formulario de registro y quiero que cuando el usuario se registre y salga el mensaje de registro completado, automáticamente inicie sesión llamando al login que tengo implementado. He probado poniendo el session_start() pero no hace nada. Si me pudierais ayudar, gracias.

Este es mi  form de registro: no están todos los campos ya que no me deja poner tanto código, pero para tener una idea.

```html
<form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Nombre -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Appellidos -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

este es el registro.php que recibe los datos y hace el post en la BD y donde sale el mensaje de regsitro completado:

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');


$un = $_POST['nombre'];
$ua = $_POST['apellidos'];
$uf = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$ue = $_POST['email'];
$uc = $_POST['contrasena'];
$ut = $_POST['telefono'];
$uci = $_POST['ciudad'];



session_start();


?><html>

<head>
    <title>Registro completado</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Su registro se ha completado correctamente.<br> Se ha enviado un correo de confirmación a su cuenta.</h1>
        <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a>
    </div>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Juan, he contestado a la pregunta con lo que yo haría en tu proyecto tal y como lo tienes ahora. Pero mi consejo es que te pases a algún framework como Laravel, CodeIgniter, etc. Cualquier problema que te encuentres tú ya se lo han encontrado ellos antes y lo han resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Añadir al proyecto alguna manera de pasar *mensajes flash* entre páginas.
2. Al final de la función de registro donde creas el usuario en la base de datos, añadir el mensaje flash "Usuario registrado correctamente" usando la sesión y llamar a la función de login con el usuario y la contraseña.
3. En la página que aparece cuando un usuario se loguea correctamente, mirar si hay algún mensaje en la sesión y mostrarlo de ser así.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es colocar

```
session_start();
```

Al inicio de tu código PHP.

Posteriormente yo validaría que efectivamente los datos han sido pasados a la segunda página (por decirlo de algún modo), utilizando el respectivo "echo".  Nos dices cómo te va con eso.  Saludos

Comment: Hola, Andres, lo he puesto el echo y me salen los datos que he utilizado en el registro correctamente

Comment: ¿Problema solucionado?  Si es así te agradezco señales la pregunta como solucionada, a fin de que otras personas la encuentren igualmente útil

Comment: Aún no, osea hice la comprobación y me salía bien, pero no me inicia sesión. Creo que tendría que llamar a mi login que tengo implementado para que inicie sesión no?